# TypoScript: tt_content.menu (Sitemap) - some Items as Text only, add sublinks to items

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have a sitemap on my page (tt_content.menu.20.8) and I have 2 questions:

1. I want some of the items displayed not as a link but just as text, like this:

[image]

Is is possible to do this in typoScript using the page IDs or something?

2. I need to manually add some subpages to "menu item 2" that are not in the page tree, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with 1., there are several options for this. What you are searching for is "doNotLinkIt", you could use that with an options split:

```
NO.doNotLinkIt = || || 1 |*| |*|
#This will unlink the third menu item
```

or with an if case:

```
#Unlinks page with uid 3
NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
NO.doNotLinkIt.if {
  value.field = uid
  equals = 3
}
```

For Nr 2.: I'll have to ask the question, why do you even want to do that. I would advise you to rather create placeholder items in the pagetree and use those.